# Current Electricity: Potentiometer

Tags: electricity

My textbook says that the EMF of the driver battery (used in the primary circuit of a potentiometer) should be more than the EMF of the cell to be determined.

I read on the web that, the driver battery is to put current through the potentiometer wire so that there shouldn't be any voltage drop across the cell. That's why it is of higher EMF. Is it true? I'm not satisfied. Please explain me a correct answer to this question.

*Thanks*

Comment: Where did you read on the web?

Comment: You should fully cite your ominous "textbook"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell with higher $emf$ decides the direction and magnitude of current.

If we want to measure $emf$ of the cell, $E_{1}$, we need a current that produces potential drop across two points, $A$ and $C_{1}$, on the resistor wire that is equal to its emf. And when this cell is connected to these two points, we get no deflection in the galvanometer.

[image]

***The maximum potential drop across the resistor due a battery is equal to its own emf.***

So if the maximum potential drop across the resistor due to the driver battery is lower than the emf of the secondary battery $(Emf_{0} < Emf_{1})$, we would never get a null point on the resistor wire for the latter.

Alternatively, this means that there will always be a current in the secondary cell because there is no null point that could have a potential drop that is the same as its emf.

Comment: This is correct, with a nice illustration!

Comment: And...here i got my answer, love from india